# Full white screen appears for few seconds before pushing the view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xcode8, pushviewcontroller

I'm getting white screen before pushing the view controller for few seconds then the UIViewController loads.

I didn't kept any break points and there is target membership. I attached the screen shots of push animation. For some push am getting it. please suggest how to proceed.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Chat", bundle: nil) 
let conversationViewCntrl = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConversationViewControllerId") as! ConversationViewController 
navigationController?.pushViewController(conversationViewCnt‌​rl, animated: true)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to push view controller with custom transition?

Comment: No.
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Chat", bundle: nil)
        let conversationViewCntrl = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConversationViewControllerId") as! ConversationViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(conversationViewCntrl, animated: true)

Comment: Could you please share the code of how are you pushing the view controller?

Comment: shared in the above comment

Comment: Are you adding constraints through code or you've added it in storyboard? If code, in which method are you adding the constraints?

Comment: No am not adding any constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code use perform segue with identifier.
In storyboard first connect your view controller/ action button with another view controller(which you want to push). Then give the Storyboard Segue Identifier Name in attribute Inspector.

[image]

```
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("shippingDetails", sender: nil)
```

Comment: I tried using segue also but no use. Push view controller not working for some push.

Comment: I came to know that simulator issue. Which works fine in iOS devices. :)

Comment: Thats good. But still i recommend to use segue rather than "storyboard.instantiateViewController".

Comment: Ok. sure .Thank you